# How to handle asynchronous tasks in axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

The arr variable below is a collection of similar arrays.

```
 function site1(url){
    return axios.get(url)
     .then((response)=>{
        if(response.status==200){
            //code for getting data
            //arr=[]---------initial value  (globally declared variable)
            for(i=1;i<=limit;i++){
                arr.push(someData);
                //after this push arr=[[item1,item2,item3,item4,item5]]
                //arr is an collection of similar arrays
                //there are many links one for each array inside arr
                //-----operation here to get someLink-------


                for(a=0;a<arr.length;a++){
                    someOtherSite(somelink,arr).then((data)=>{
                        arr=data;

                    });
                }
            }


        }

        return arr;

    })

  }

function someOtherSite(url,arr){
 return axios.get(url)
          .then(response=>{
         //get some dataItem
          arr[arr.length-1].push(dataItem);
          return arr;
   })
 }
```

for function call :

```
site1(url).then(data=>{
     console.log(data);
   })
```

I wanted the value of arr to be like this:
arr=[[item1,item2,item3,item4,item5,dataItem],.......]
but the return happens before and the value of arr is displayed without the dataItem.
How to i make the returning of the value wait and occur after the process has been completed.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Instead, you should return only Axios get and pass the success and error handlers as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

Axios is a promise based HTTP client, so you need to wait axios to return, use **async function** and **await** for axios.get, also use **Promise** to wait for operations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Here is an example about your code:

```
  function site1(url){
            return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
                await axios.get(url)
                 .then((response)=>{
                            //code for getting data
                            //arr=[]---------initially  globally declared
                        for(i=1;i<=limit;i++){
                            arr.push(someData);
                            for(a=0;a<arr.length;a++){
                                someOtherSite(somelink,arr).then((data)=>{
                                arr=data;
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        resolve(arr)
                    })
                 .catch(err=>{
                    reject(err)
                 })
            })
   }

function someOtherSite(url,arr){
    return new Promise(async(resolve,reject)=>{
         await axios.get(url)
                  .then(response=>{
                 //get some dataItem
                  arr[arr.length-1].push(dataItem);
                  resolve(arr);
                    })
                  .catch(err=>{
                    reject(err)
                  })
    })
}
```

for function call :

```
    site1(url).then(data=>{
     console.log(data);
   })
```

Comment: now my code is giving an error "ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1" .How can i resolve this issue?